# How to prevent GOBACK button for specific URL in Android Webview?

Tags: java, android, webview

I have an web application that work on my Android `WebView` with out problem.

Here is my Android app launcher code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView webView;

private String urlAddress = "http://www.YourDomainName.com/TheLoginPage";
private String loadingTxt = "Loading";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toast loadingMsg = Toast.makeText(this,
            loadingTxt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    loadingMsg.show();

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(urlAddress);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
    webView.setInitialScale(1);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                }
                return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Every thing is working.

**My Question:** the default start page in the WebView is the web application login page. After a successful login process I want to prevent (build in) **GO BACK** button to back page to the default start page (login page) since I am successfully logged in?

**Note:** I will still use the **GO BACK** button to the rest of the web application or if I logout out again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here how I solved it, I have added `if equals` statement to compare the URL of the page that comes after the login process with the WebView URL, if they are identical then GO BACK is disallowed and a message "You are logged in", that way I prevent GO BACK. Here is the code and it works for me:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                String url = new String("http://www.YourDomainName.com/PageAfterSuccessfulLogin");
                String webUrl = new String(webView.getUrl());

                if (url.equals(webUrl)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "You are logged in",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Back",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        webView.goBack();
                    }
                }
                return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks maytham-maytham, it works charmly.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                String url = new String("https://www.domain name.com/index.php?logged=login%20successfully");
                String webUrl = new String(webView.getUrl());

                if (url.equals(webUrl)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "You are logged in",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {


                    url = new String("https://www.domain name.com/main.php");
                    webUrl = new String(webView.getUrl());

                    if (url.equals(webUrl)) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Access Denied",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                 else
                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Back",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        webView.goBack();
                    }
                }
                return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In which ever activity you want the back button to be disabled - DO THIS

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    return;
}
```

You have to add this as a global function.

As in your case you want your back button to work in some cases and not work in some-

You can do this inside the `onBackPressed()`

```
if(BackButton_Dont_Work_Condition)
  return

else 
  super.onBackPressed()
```