# How can I prevent going back in react-native-webview?

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

My app uses react-native-webview and set allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures to true.
I want to prevent going back on a specific page.
For example, after navigating to the home page from the login page, I want to make sure that I cannot go back.
I wonder if blocking back is possible in react-native-webview.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be sure but your question sure sounds like a React Navigation issue, particularly concerning Auth. Flow. Well, should that be the case, there's a pretty well written documentation on Auth Flow with good example(s) [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/)

Hope that helps in solving your issue.

Comment: We will not controlling back handler in App, just control in webpage.

Comment: Hi. Were you able to get a solution on this?
My thinking is if the page is a webpage, then you can use an if-else to control disabling the back button as state using the url. What I mean is something like what is seen in this answer for Java code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27749288/17180119

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict back button from onNavigationStateChange

```
onNavigationStateChange={(navState) => {
        if (navState.canGoBack) {
          navigation.setParams({
            headerLeftInfo: {
              title: '',
              onPress: () => //TODO:back button logic,
            },
          });
        } else {
          navigation.setParams({
            headerLeftInfo: null,
          });
        }
      }}
```

Reference: https://www.reactnativeschool.com/integrating-react-navigation-back-button-with-a-webview

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use **onShouldStartLoadWithRequest** and simply return false when request contains URL you do not want to allow.

From [documentation](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#onshouldstartloadwithrequest):

```
<WebView
  source={{ uri: 'https://reactnative.dev' }}
  onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={(request) => {
    // Only allow navigating within this website
    return request.url.startsWith('https://reactnative.dev');
  }}
/>
```